# How to validate ManyToManyField before saving?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have Models like:

```
School:
    id
    name

Teacher:
    id:
    name:
    school = ForeignKey(School)

Student:
    id:
    name:
    school = ForeignKey(School)
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher)
```

I need to validate the student and teacher have the same school when user create Student object from a form, how should I do that?

Comment: Can you share your form?

Comment: @schillingt I use modelform_factory to generate the form